# Flatsome and Angelleye

Tags: php, wordpress, requiredfieldvalidator, notice

I'm trying to figure out how to move the Error messages from above the breadcrumbs on the Checkout page to just above the Billing form.
[image]
I'm using the Angelleye Paypal Express Plugin with Flatsome. I'm doing my changes on the function.php of the child theme. I have this code in the Error.php from /notices/woocommerce

```
<ul class="woocommerce-error message-wrapper" role="alert">
<?php foreach ( $notices as $notice ) : ?>
    <li<?php echo wc_get_notice_data_attr( $notice ); ?>>
        <div class="message-container container alert-color medium-text-center">
            <span class="message-icon icon-close"></span>
            <?php echo wc_kses_notice( $notice['notice'] ); ?>
        </div>
    </li>
```

I have deleted the code for testing and the issue was gone, however, I would like to place it above the Billing details if possible. Around the

```
<div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper"</div>
```

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please place your code in `functions.php`. Tweak the code if needed. Not tested, believe it will work.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );

function woocommerce_output_all_notices() { ?>
<div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper"
    <ul class="woocommerce-error message-wrapper" role="alert">
        <?php foreach ( $notices as $notice ) : ?>
            <li<?php echo wc_get_notice_data_attr( $notice ); ?>>
                <div class="message-container container alert-color medium-text-center">
                    <span class="message-icon icon-close"></span>
                    <?php echo wc_kses_notice( $notice['notice'] ); ?>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div
<?php    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mainul for your response. I have tried the code and had no success. It says cannot : Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 3773 of file wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php. Please fix and try saving again. Cannot redeclare woocommerce_output_all_notices(). I have altered the code a little as well and the result was another <div> with the same class name was made at the top with the same result.

Comment: Did you named `woocommerce_output_all_notices` function multiple times? Can you change your function name and try again?

Comment: Sorrry for the late reply. Didn't work, when I tried to change the function name in line 3773 of wc-template-functions it killed the website. I have found a plugin from themehigh which fixes the issue. Now, just need to find a way to fix the notification error on the account page. Thanks :)